# useEffect fires before DOM is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

I created a hook which calculates distance between every element on specific page (the one You are currently on) and top of the page. Its supposed to fade elements when they are less than 100px from the bottom of the page. It worked fine until i placed additional component (OverviewBox). After that it stopped working. Now it works again only because i wrapped the hook with 2 setTimeout functions. but off course its a bad solution. How can i make it work without the setTimeout Functions?

useFadeElements hook:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";


//the hook checks every element (unless excluded) which is inside the parentElement. if distance between bottom of viewport
//and top of the element is less than 100px, the element gets "hidden" class.

export const useFadeElements = (parentElementId, excludeTags) => {

const [elementsAndDistances, setElementsAndDistances] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=>{

   setTimeout(()=>{
       setTimeout(()=>{
         
           const targetElement = document.getElementById(parentElementId)
           let elementsInside = targetElement.getElementsByTagName("*")


           elementsInside = [...elementsInside]

           //if user wants to exclude some elements from fading, he passes array of tags he wants to exclude.
           if (excludeTags.length>0){
               elementsInside = elementsInside.filter((el) => {
                   return !excludeTags.includes((el.tagName))
               })
           }

           //create array of objects that contain both reference to element and distance between the element and top of the page
           let elementsAndDistances = []
           elementsInside.forEach((el)=>{
               //add unhidden class in order to show element back/ change opacity to 1
               el.classList.add("unhidden")

               let distance = 0
               //loop up the dom
               let temporaryEl = el;
               do {
                   distance+=temporaryEl.offsetTop
                   temporaryEl = temporaryEl.offsetParent;
               }while (temporaryEl)
               //js may sometimes return distance below 0 due to its problems with precise calculations
               distance = distance < 0 ? 0 : distance;

               elementsAndDistances.push({
                   el,
                   distance
               })
           })

           setElementsAndDistances(elementsAndDistances)
       },0)
   },0)

},[])


useEffect(()=>{
    //check if element distance from its top to the bottom of viewport is smaller that 100px,
    // if so, hide it (change opacity to 0)
    const checkElementDistance = (elementAndDistance) => {
        if ((window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) -100 < elementAndDistance.distance){
            elementAndDistance.el.classList.add("hidden")
        }else elementAndDistance.el.classList.remove("hidden")
    }

    if (elementsAndDistances){
        window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
            elementsAndDistances.forEach((elementAndDistance)=>{
                checkElementDistance(elementAndDistance)
            })
        })
    }
    return ()=>window.removeEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
        elementsAndDistances.forEach((elementAndDistance)=>{
            checkElementDistance(elementAndDistance)
        })
    })
},[elementsAndDistances])

return {elementsAndDistances}
}
```

page I use the hook on:

```
import "./AboutUs.css"
import Carousel from "../../components/carousel/Carousel";
import {useFadeElements} from "../../hooks/useFadeElements";
import Form from "../../components/form/Form";
import OverviewBox from "../../components/overviewBox/OverviewBox";

const productFeaturesDetails = [
    {
        title: "Wyjazd tylko dla kobiet",
        info: "Daj się zaprosić na wyprawę w gronie inspirujących kobiet! Naładujesz baterie i znajdziesz przestrzeń na zaprzyjaźnienie się z najważniejszą osobą w Twoim życiu – z Tobą samą  Przygotowaliśmy dla Ciebie zajęcia z medytacji, praktykę jogi, a także warsztaty i kursy biznesowe. I to wszystko pod palmami! No chyba, że od palm wolisz słoneczną Toskanię.",
        imgSrc: "http://wolne.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/strona-glowna-5.jpg"
    },
    {
        title: "Wakacje i rozwój osobisty w jednym",
        info: "Obiecujemy, że jadąc z nami znajdziesz przestrzeń i na bycie inspiracją, i na bycie inspirowaną. Naszymi głównymi wartościami są wsparcie i bezpieczeństwo. W grupie wspaniałych, podobnych Tobie kobiet z całej Polski nie tylko fantastycznie wypoczniesz, lecz zyskasz także możliwości na ciekawe znajomości. Kto wie, może zostaną z Tobą do końca życia?",
        imgSrc: "http://wolne.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/strona-glowna-4.jpg"
    },
     {
        title: "Dla kogo?",
        info: "Nasze podróże dedykujemy kobietom, które są głodne wyzwań i pięknych momentów, chcą zwiedzać świat, a zarazem lubią mieć towarzystwo i wsparcie w podróży.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Dzięki WOLNYM możesz podróżować solo, jednocześnie zachowując wsparcie płynące z grupy. My zajmiemy się organizacją. Ty w tym czasie możesz cieszyć się słońcem ",
        imgSrc: "http://wolne.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/strona-glowna--scaled.jpg"
    },
     {
        title: "Gdzie możesz pojechać?",
        info: "Sky is the limit! Możliwości jest wiele: możesz dać się oczarować bieli greckich domów, słońcu Toskanii, paryskim nocom lub balijskim rytuałom. A może zainteresuje Cię bogactwo hinduskiej kuchni lub gwar azjatyckich  ulic? Wybór należy do Ciebie: wybierz kierunek, a my zajmiemy się resztą. Daj się zaprosić na przygodę życia!",
        imgSrc: "http://wolne.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/strona-glowna-3.jpg"
    }
]

const blogNewPosts = [
    {
        title: "Właściwości aloesu o których nie słyszałaś",
        info: "Często chwalony za swoje kojące właściwości, aloes jest najczęściej używany jako maść do stosowania miejscowego na oparzenia słoneczne i otarcia skóry. czy wiedziałaś, że ta magiczna roślina OFERUJE JESZCZE LEPSZE właściwości lecznicze, gdy jest przyjmowana doustnie?Większość z nas wie, że obecność aloesu w kosmetykach pomaga nawilżyć skórę i spowalnia jej starzenie się. Warto jednak przyjrzeć się temu, jakie właściwości oferuje…",
        imgSrc: "http://wolne.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/maria-alvares-de-carvalho-jOzSjzIRrTU-unsplash-scaled.jpg"
    }
]

const AboutUs = ({excursions}) => {
        const {elementsAndDistances} = useFadeElements("about-us__columns", ["DIV"])


    return (
        <div className="about-us">
            <div className="content-container">
                <div id="about-us__columns" className="about-us__columns">
                    <div className="about-us--left-column .about-us--column">
                        {productFeaturesDetails.map((productFeatureDetails)=>{
                            return(
                                <OverviewBox
                                        key={productFeatureDetails.imgSrc}
                                        title={productFeatureDetails.title}
                                        info={productFeatureDetails.info}
                                        titleSize="h2"
                                        imgSrc={productFeatureDetails.imgSrc}
                                />
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <div className="about-us--right-column .about-us--column">
                        <OverviewBox title="Cześć!" imgSrc="http://wolne.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/denys-nevozhai-z0nVqfrOqWA-unsplash.jpg"/>
                        <h2 className="about-us__subtitle">Co nowego na blogu</h2>
                        {blogNewPosts.map((postDetails)=>{
                            return <OverviewBox
                                titleSize="h3"
                                key={postDetails.imgSrc}
                                imgSrc={postDetails.imgSrc}
                                title={postDetails.title}
                                info={postDetails.info}
                            />
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Carousel data={excursions} title="Wyprawy w naszej ofercie"/>
            <div className="content-container">
                <Form title="Napisz do nas" topTitle="Potrzebujesz więcej informacji?"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AboutUs;
```

overviewBox component:

```
    import "./OverviewBox.css"
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const OverviewBox = ({title, info, date, imgSrc, titleSize="h2"}) => {

    const [TitleTag, setTitleTag] = useState(null)

    useEffect(()=>{
        setTitleTag(`${titleSize}`)
    },[titleSize])


return (
    <>
        {TitleTag &&   <div className="overview-box">
            <TitleTag className="overview-box__title">{title}</TitleTag>
            <p className="overview-box__info">{info}</p>
            <img className="overview-box__img" src={imgSrc} alt="img"/>
            <span className="overview-box__date">{date}</span>
        </div>}

        </>

    );
};

export default OverviewBox;
```

Comment: Try using one requestAnimationFrame(() => { ... your code } ) - which does a render cycle and does not have a timeout value that is arbitrary.

Comment: likewise, you could do all of the dom manipulation. and then just put the setElements and distances function in requestAnimationFrame to trigger a re-render after all the weird dom updates are completed.